# Render React local nested components

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to implement a "local" component?

```
<Page>
    <Header> ... </Header>
</Page>
```

vs.

```
<Page>
    <Page.Header> ... </Page.Header>
</Page>
```

How can Header be implemented (if at all possible) such that in the first example React will create Page.Header rather than some "global" Header?

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 0):

I recommend implementing a Header component (or name it CustomHeader) which takes one or more props.

```
<Page>
    <CustomHeader passedProp={...}> ... </CustomHeader>
</Page>
```